# Value is not used (unused in scope) in Django Framework

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-rest-framework

Hi I am new to Django framework and I have followed this tutorial 
[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qgGIqRFvFFk&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBlmzzFcLgDhKTTfNLfX1IK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcief.png)
 in order to create a website, but when I ran the Music app, it's not executing and in my views.py, there is an error which is showed by underlining the "request" in the "index(request)", that says the parameter 'request' value is not used. Below are the snippets of the codes:
[**views.py**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcief.png)

```
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
return HttpResponse("<h1>This is Music App Page")
```

**music/urls.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
return HttpResponse("<h1>This is Music App Page")
```

**website/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^music/', include('music.urls')),
]
```

In the first image (i.e in Views.py) "request" which is highlighted in red is throwing error stating that parameter 'request' value is not used (unused in scope). 
I have followed the exact tutorial as mentioned in the link, can somebody please help? Thanks.!

Comment: are you sure the music urls that you posted is correct?? and it doesnt matter, the request parameter works like that

Comment: You haven't copied your `music/urls.py` =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no error here. Your text editor is trying to be helpful by warning you about a style issue, but there is nothing that will prevent your code from running.

Comment: so what is` PEP8` proper way to write views that does not uses request data?

Answer (score 2):

There is no error on your code. If you want to get rid of PEP8 warning, you can simply put

```
# noinspection PyUnusedLocal
```

on top of your functions